# How can a const expr be evaluated so fast

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

I have been trying out const expressions which are evaluated at compile time. 
But I played with an example that seems incredibly fast when executed at compile time.

```
#include<iostream> 

constexpr long int fib(int n) { 
    return (n <= 1)? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
} 

int main () {  
    long int res = fib(45); 
    std::cout << res; 
    return 0; 
}
```

When I run this code it takes about 7 seconds to run. So far so good. But when I change `long int res = fib(45)` to `const long int res = fib(45)` it takes not even a second.
To my understanding it is evaluated at compile time. 
**But the compilation takes about 0.3 seconds**

How can the compiler evaluate this so quickly, but at runtime it takes so much more time?
I'm using gcc 5.4.0.

Comment: Are you using optimised code?

Comment: I conjecture that the compiler caches the the function calls to `fib`. The implementation of the fibonacci numbers you have above is preeeeeetty slow. Try caching the function values in runtime code and it will much faster.

Comment: This recursive fibonacci is terribly inefficient (it has an exponential runtime), so my guess is that the compile time evaluation is more clever than this and optimizes the calculation.

Comment: The compiler could fully evaluate `constexpr` functions at compile-time, when used for example to initialize a compile-time constant (like `const long int res = ...` will be, but `long ing res = ...` will *not* be).

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes I compiled it with -O3.

Comment: I we assume that the compiler caches function calls the function needs to be eveluated only 46 times (once for each possible argument 0-45) instead of 2^45 times. However I don't know if gcc works like that.

Comment: With -03, there is only one recursive call each time, so the runtime is not exponential (or at least that's how I interpret the output): https://godbolt.org/z/55vR5X

Comment: Confirming my suspicion, using `const long int res = fib(45);` indeed evaluates the `fib(45)` call at compile-time (https://godbolt.org/z/pZyAG3).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know. But how can the compilation be so quick when the evaluation takes so much time at runtime?

Comment: I have checked the compiler output. You may find interesting with 5.4 the function is not completely eliminated, you need at least 6.1 for that.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler caches smaller values and does not need to recompute as much as the runtime version does.
(The optimiser is very good and generates lots of code including trickery with special cases that are incomprehensible to me; the naive 2^45 recursions would take hours.)

If you also store previous values:

```
int cache[100] = {1, 1};

long int fib(int n) {
    int res = cache[n];
    return res ? res : (cache[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2));
}
```

the runtime version is much faster than the compiler.

Comment: There is no way to avoid recursing twice, unless you do some caching. Do you think the optimizer implements some caching? Are you able to show this in the compiler output, as that would be really interesting?

Comment: ... it is also possible compiler instead of caching compiler is able to prove some relationship between fib(n-2) and fib(n-1) and instead of calling fib(n-1) it uses to fib(n-2) value to compute that. I think that matches what I see in the output of 5.4 whne removing constexpr and using -O2.

Comment: Do you have a link or other source that explains what optimizations can be done at compile time?

Comment: As long as the observable behaviour is unchanged, the optimizer is free to do almost anything. Given `fib` function has no side effects (references no external variables, output depends on inputs only), with a clever optimizer a lot can be done.

Comment: @Suma It's no problem to recurse only once. Since there is an iterative version, there is of course also a recursive version, that uses for example tail recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You may find interesting with 5.4 the function is not completely eliminated, you need at least 6.1 for that.

I do not think there is any caching happening. I am convinced the optimizer is smart enough to prove relationship between `fib(n - 2)` and `fib(n-1)` and avoids the second call completely. This is GCC 5.4 output (obtained from godbolt) with no `constexpr` and -O2:

```
fib(long):
        cmp     rdi, 1
        push    r12
        mov     r12, rdi
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        jle     .L4
        mov     rbx, rdi
        xor     ebp, ebp
.L3:
        lea     rdi, [rbx-1]
        sub     rbx, 2
        call    fib(long)
        add     rbp, rax
        cmp     rbx, 1
        jg      .L3
        and     r12d, 1
.L2:
        lea     rax, [r12+rbp]
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
.L4:
        xor     ebp, ebp
        jmp     .L2
```

I have to admit I do not understand the output with -O3 - the code generated is surprisingly complex, with lots of memory accesses and pointer arithmetics and it is quite possible there is some caching (memoization) done with those settings.

Comment: I think I am wrong. There is a loop at .L3, and the fib is looping over all lower fibs. With -O2 it is still exponential.